# How to run custom model validations for M2M in clean() when adding a new model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model in Django with a `ManyToManyField` relationship to another model. Something that looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    models = models.ManyToManyField(
        OtherModel,
        related_name='my_models',
        )
```

In my `clean()` method, I have a bunch of custom validation rules that are run in the model fields. Some of them actually run in the ManyToManyField. All validations work fine when creating model instances with an uploader tool that parses data from a csv into a model instance or when saving an existing model in the Admin.

However, I want to be able to add model instances directly in the Admin but because of the ManyToMany relationship, which I found out that is not set until after the `save()` method, some validations throw a `ValueError: "<MyModel: Some Model>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.` ([ref][1])

Then, what I did is a very ugly hack to to the validation in the `clean()` method to bypass it by catching the `ValueError`:

```
def _some_validation(self):
    try:
        if self.my_models.count() == 0:
            raise ValidationError("This is an error message thrown by ...")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Then it works fine to add a model instance via Admin, however, it doesn't run the validation on the ManyToMany field, allowing for inconsistent data.

Is there a way that I can re-run the `clean()` method after the M2M relationship is set when creating a new model instance via the `add_form` in the admin?

Note: I am not using custom forms as I found no need since the Django's default generated add form in the Admin satisfies my needs.
[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to listen to the  m2m_changed signal

```
def my_models_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    # Do something
    pass

m2m_changed.connect(my_models_changed, sender=MyModel.my_models.through)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed

Comment: than you for your answer. I might be wrong but can the m2m_changed signal raise a ValidationError?